# Can I close wrapper inputstream or outputstream class in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, inputstream, outputstream

I  have a code like...

```
class DemoServlet extends HttpServlet
 {    
  doPost(HttpReqeust httpRequest,HttpResponse httpResponse)
       {
           try {
               ObjectInputStream input=new ObjectInputStream(httpRequest.getInputStream());
               Object ojb=input.readObject();
               ObjectOutputStream output=new ObjectOutputStream(httpResponse.getOutputStream());
               }
           catch(Exception ex){
                  ex.printStackTrace();
              }
           finally{
               input.close();  // it is necessary to close or it will handle by the servlet container to
               output.close(); // the outputstream or inputstream.
           }
      }}
```

I know that close for httpRequest.getInputStream() and httpResponse.getOutputStream() is not required but is it right to close the Stream class which is wrapping the inputstream and outputstream.Is they create some issue or throw exception.

Comment: Look into the try with resources pattern. You're potentially leaking streams, there. And catching all exceptions is generally bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

The wrapper streams/readers/writers in the Java SE close the underlying streams (when they get closed), so if you want to keep them open, do not close the wrappers.

Edit:
The [Reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#close%28%29)'s `close()` documentation probably explains better. The wrappers (like [InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#close%28%29)) usually extend this class for the interfaces without overriding the documentation.

In case of [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#close%28%29) the case is similar you can check the behaviour in [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.java#ObjectOutputStream.close%28%29).

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer with some example.So,I can understand it properly and thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sahil Added some example, hope it helps.

Comment: it means overall conclusion is that if I close the ObjectInputStream or ObjectOutputStream then my httpRequest.getInputStream() or httpResponse.getOutputStream() respectively are also closed.So, you want to say that it is better to remain them open and later it is automatically close by the container. Am I right ?

Comment: @Sahil Yes ofcourse if you close ObjectInputStream you are closing httpRequest.getInputStream(). Its the same object. If you leave them open the container will close it. You should close it if you have no filters that will execute after the Servlet call.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start it form the [The Java EE 5 Tutorial - Filtering Requests and Responses](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html#bnagd) where it is explained in details along with examples that how you can customize the Requests and Responses using [HttpServletResponseWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html) and [HttpServletRequestWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html)